# What is a "variational characterization"?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

When people say the Courant-Fischer theorem gives a "[variational characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)" of the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix, what do they mean? I understand the statement of the theorem, but not the meaning/implication of the word *variational*.

Is it somehow related to variational inference or calculus of variations?

Comment: My educated guess is that "variational" refers to the fact that the solution can be obtained by solving a maximization/minimization problem, similarly to how the calculus of variations considers problems that are solved by maximizing/minimizing functionals